# countif statement what wont count 00:00

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

Any help would be appreciated. I need the `CountIf` statement to count all the data points that are equal to 00:00. The column is formatted for 24hr time due to other formulas.  The 00:00 is a product of an if statement. I have tried many options but it won’t calculate unless I reformat  the column to general, but in doing that it messes up my time formation which I need to be 24hr format. Thanks.

```
Sub Sample()
Dim result As Long, firstrow As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

'~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    '~~> Find Lastrow in Col D
    lastrow = .Range("V" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    '~~> Set First row
    firstrow = 16

    '~~> Set your range
    Set rng = .Range("V" & firstrow & ":V" & lastrow)

    '~~> Put relevant values
    .Range("U" & lastrow + 3).Value = "No Slip Time"
    .Range("V" & lastrow + 3).Value = _
     Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "*00:00")
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: are there only time values in your `rng`? if so did you try simply this way: `...=Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "<>0")`? or there are date+time?

Comment: no only time  source data

Comment: did you consider writing your own 'user-defined-function'?

Comment: Try without the `*`? Also, if you highlighted one of the cells, what shows in the formula bar? "0"?

Comment: have you considered in your code first reformat the cells to General, do the CountIf worksheet formula, then reformat back to 24 hr time?

Comment: no only time  source data                                        4/3/13  6:15 AM   6:41:56 AM  NA  NA NA   the data files look like this   6:15  6:41  0:26   00:00  0   0

Comment: KazJaw that line of code didnt work.

Comment: Could you share image of cells an formula bar values?

Comment: glh I did a wild card * and '

Comment: glh... I did a wild card * and "00:00" I even changed it to countif "1"... it only worked when i changed the format to general, but then it messed up the time. I have several sheet so changing the format will take too much time. Can a macro be used to change the column back and forth. How would i do that on column w row 16 if its an option. thanks

Comment: `range("w:w").numberformat ="@"` will give a general format

Comment: =IF((K16="NA"),"00:00",IF(K16<>"na",K16)) code for column v

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng.value2 , "0")`

Comment: `=IF((K16=NA()),0,IF(K16<>na(),K16))`

Comment: it shows #N/A in all the cells thats not correct. Cant do a count on it. Am I missing something

Answer (score 3):

**Notes:**

- The string **"00:00"** and time **0** are not the same.
- **Date and time is a number** where 0 is midnight, 1 a day and 0.5 is 12 hours.

  [image: zero compare]

Based on your comments you have the following formula in column v, `=IF((K16="NA"),"00:00",IF(K16<>"na",K16))`, use this instead.

```
=IF(Upper(K16)="NA",0,K16)
```

If you have `#N/A` in cell K16 you need to replace the above `"NA"` with `NA()`.

Also once done you can use the `countif` as follows.

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng.value2 , "0")
```

Comment: Cheers @KazJaw. It's clear to me when someone needs help.  ;)

Comment: @glh, me either. I traced your conversation ready to help but you did it perfect :)

Comment: @user2254486, again, as stated below your question, please mark this and other your questions as solved, it is really welcomed here.

Comment: i thought it worked also.... its works if I change the format to something other than 24hr time but I dont want to do that each time . The time gets messed up. So is it a format issues with no work around. Is there something with the countif that it wont count time ie 00:00.I think the countif format is correct??? Right

Comment: `"00:00"` is time formatting equivalent for simple `0` value. if you go according to `if..upper..` function from @glh `countif` will recognise 0 whichever range format you have (general or time). I analysed proposed solution and it works fine for me...

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I am to sure how to using the rating but it helped

Comment: There is a grey tick to mark a answer and up arrows to say it helps